# PHP syntax Error when attempting to compile reCAPTCHA code?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm attempting to create a reCAPTCHA human verification box on my website, however I cannot get past an error in my php code. I'm sure it's simple, I just can't get past it. I took out my site and private keys for security reasons.

My error when compiling:

> "FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected ';' on line number 8"

Here's my code, thanks in advance:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['ContactButton'])){
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $privatekey = "--- My Private Key ---";
        $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$#privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        $data = json_decode($response);

        if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){
            ////true - what happens when user is verified
            header('Location: ExampleCaptcha.php?CaptchaPass=True');
        }else{
            ////false - what happens when the user ISNT verified
            header('Location: ExampleCaptcha.php?CaptchaFail=True');
        }
    }

?>




<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>



    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' action='index.html'>
            <input type='text' name='inp' /><br>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--- My Site Key ---"></div><br>
            <input type='submit' /><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which line is line 8?

Comment: rather than `if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){` try `if( property_exists( $data, 'success' ) && $data->success==true ){`

Comment: @RamRaider there are various improvements OP can make to his code, but this doesn't relate to their current issue.

Comment: @Martin Line 8 is... $data = json_decode($response);

Comment: see my answer, @IsaacWorley I'm pretty sure the issue is in your `file_get_contents` string

Comment: I didn't know until now that you can use 'AND' rather than '&&' so I learned something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is here: `file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$#privatekey.` there is a hash (comment) symbol in the string which looks like it is in the wrong place, (typo?)... but your string looks a mess overall. Improve this. The Error will resolve itself.

Remove the `#` you have incorrectly placed. variables can not start with a symbol.

...

```
$string = $url."?secret=".$#privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                         ^^^^ //What's this? Remove '#' 

$response = file_get_contents($string);
```

Comment: Beautiful, the error was removed. However, when trying to access the index.php file on my website, I receive a 404 error. If I switch the file extension to index.html, the reCAPTCHA loads perfectly, but the php code isn't being executed and is displayed at the top of my webpage. Any ideas on why the php file won't execute?

Comment: pages need to be `.php` to run PHP code, I don't know why there's an error 404 -- but that's a classic File Not Found, so double and triple check that the location of the file is where the URL is pointing. @IsaacWorley

Comment: And if this answer fixes your problem please tick the tick next to my answer. Thanks :) @IsaacWorley